# Testing Generic Angular Components (not Generic Class)

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to test an Angular Generic Component?

As an example, if I have

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent<T> implements OnInit {
   public constructor(
      private context: T
   );
}
```

Where T can be any number of classes.

Then eventually I want to write a Jasmine test, but I am not able to determine the proper syntax for when creating the test fixture:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent<MyTestObject>);
```

It is here that TSLint complains:

```
Value of type 'typeof MyComponent' is not callable. Did you mean to include new?
```

It clearly thinks that I need a constructor (?), but is unclear how or where to implement that.

Is what I am attempting even possible?  I can find examples of generic components.  I ***can't*** find examples on setting up a test fixture / component

Answer (score 5):

The [TestBed.createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBedStatic#createcomponent) function in itself is generic and returns a componentFixture, so that is where you should apply the generic. For your use-case you should do:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent<MyComponent<MyTestObject>>(MyComponent);
```

Remember to have declared your fixture as

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent<MyTestObject>>;
```

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that `TestBed.createComponent()` expects a javascript class as an argument. `MyComponent<MyTestObject>` is not valid javascript.

Perhaps you intended to put `TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent as typeof MyComponent<MyTestObject>)` (or maybe the proper syntax is `MyComponent as (typeof MyComponent)<MyTestObject>` -- I'm not sure).

Alternatively, if `TestBed#createComponent()` is generic, you'd probably want to do `TestBed.createComponent<MyComponent<MyTestObject>>(MyComponent)`.

Comment: This doesn't work =) still interested in this matter